# How can I use Fragments to create layout in the image displayed

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

Here is the image screenshot:

[image]

My query is how can I implement the Stack layout shown? I have scoured the resource files and most only show how to implement two fragments.

Would anyone please give me any example of how I can create the Stack fragment as shown?

Will appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas anyone? I really need some major help!!

Comment: +1 for nice presentation guys

Answer (score 2):

If your fragments are closely tied together, just don't run them in separate activities. For the single pane case you can just switch fragments within one activity.

Otherwise, if you do want to separate them between activities, you need to use the onActivityResult() model for propagating results back, and in the dual-pane case "emulate" it by just having the second call onActivityResult() of the first fragment. Note that Fragment.setTargetFragment() includes a request code argument to facilitate this.

```
I have activity A loading Fragment F1 which loads fragment F2
```

IMHO, fragments should not load other fragments. Activities load fragments, based upon available screen space. Fragments should neither know nor care whether any other fragment exists in the current activity, or if other fragments are in other activities.

```
I have F2 calling back to activity A to pop it off of the stack. Should I then be looking at passing a message to F1 to do what it needs to do?
```

Yes.

```
What I'm wondering is whether I'm on the right track with regards passing messages back and forwards via the parent activity or is there a more direct way of F1 responding to F2 performing something that requires it to be closed and F1 do what it needs to do.
```

I would not have F1 even know that F2 exists, or vice versa. When the user does something in F1 that should result in a major context shift (e.g., display some other fragment/activity), F1 should let the hosting activity know, perhaps via a listener interface registered with F1 (to support multiple possible hosting activities). The activity would then arrange for F2 to appear, either in its own activity or in another activity. Similarly, when F2 wraps up, it would let its hosting activity know via a listener interface, and that activity can route control back to the appropriate spot.

I am somewhat skeptical of your whole "F2 performs an action which should result in it being closed" approach, unless F2 is a DialogFragment.

Comment: Mike I like your argument. Do you have any link where I can refer as to how to switch fragments within one activity?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is given below
Please tweak width and heights according to the use case

For Landscape use

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ..>
   <fragment android:name="com.example.FragmentA"
        android:id="@+id/fa"
        android:layout_width="xdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>
      <fragment android:name="com.example.FragmentB"
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_width="ydp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <fragment android:name="com.example.FragmentC"
        android:id="@+id/fc"
        android:layout_width="zdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For Portrait view use

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ..>
   <fragment android:name="com.example.FragmentA"
        android:id="@+id/fa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="Xdp" />
  <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <fragment android:name="com.example.FragmentB"
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_width="ydp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <fragment android:name="com.example.FragmentC"
        android:id="@+id/fc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_cotent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep. Small query though. IS there a way for the fragment layout_width to be set programatically so that it is not fixed in the xml file? Much thanks.

Comment: Yes you can set the Width in the view returned by onCreateView method of the fragment

Comment: Rajdeep, please excuse my ignorance but I am newbie, could you please help me write some small code in the onCreate View showing how the width can be set? Much thanks.

Comment: Please refer to the following link.http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/ContentFragment.html. Try calling setWidth(int ...) on mContentView